# Laravel and Baum

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just beginning my adventure with laravel. I installed the add-on baum. But I do not know how to use it. I've created a controller and I try to add a category but I get the error: FatalErrorException in CategoriesController.php line 28: Class 'Category' not found.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('admin.categories.index');
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('admin.categories.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $root = Category::create(['name' => 'R1']);
    }
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: use App\Category in place of use Category;

Comment: Class 'App\Category' not found :(

Comment: You need to find correct path Category model, that you're using

Comment: I have file app/Category.php

use Baum\Node;

/**
* Category
*/
class Category extends Node {

  ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table named as `categories` and you are trying to access that table using Laravel ORM(eloquent). At first you need to create a model of `Categories` table. Write the following command in your terminal after entering into the project directory:

`php artisan make:model Category`

After running this command you see that a file `Category` has been created into the `App` folder. This file contains the `Category` class which extends `Model` class. This class represent your `Categories` table of db. If the table name is not `categories` then you have to add a property in the `Category` class a follow.

`protected $table = "category"; //If you table name is not categories`

Now, you can access the `Category` model from you controller. To do so, you have to add the following line before the `CategoriesController` class declaration:

`use App\Category;`

Now, you shouldn't have the error that you have mentioned in your question. Best of luck.

Comment: I used php artisan baum:install Category
Is it not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI i noticed that the baum generator for the model (php artisan baum:install) actually places the wrong namespace at the top. It puts namespace app; when it should be namespace App; with capital A. This issue drove me mad for almost an hour when I almost ripped baum out, but then finally realized that was the issue.